# string replacement of \1 (python)

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, substring

I want to remove the comma inside the [] in the string below:

> > > columns_data = '6, 7, 1729, 7, 7, [5, 6, 4, 6], [66, 55] ,45, 23'
> > >       I want it to be
> > >       '6, 7, 1729, 7, 7, [5 6 4 6], [66 55] ,45, 23'

I do the following but it doesn't work ...

> > > re.sub('([[^[]*])', str(r'\1').replace(","," ") , columns_data )
> > >       '6, 7, 1729, 7, 7, [5, 6, 4, 6], [66, 55] ,45, 23'

Comment: Do you need the solution with only regex or any solution would work?

Comment: Pass a callable as the replacement argument. `re.sub(reg_pattern, lambda x: x.group().replace(",",""), columns_data)`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import re  
text =  '6, 7, 1729, 7, 7, [5, 6, 4, 6], [66, 55] ,45, 23'  
re.sub(r'(\[.*?\])', lambda x: x.group().replace(',', ''), text)
```

Output:

```
'6, 7, 1729, 7, 7, [5 6 4 6], [66 55] ,45, 23'
```